# Authenticate Outlook AddIn to Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations (using yo Office-Generator and MSAL)

Tags: typescript, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, azure-ad-msal

I want to create an Outlook add-in that can retrieve data from D365FO using OData.

I used the yo Office generator to create an add-in with SSO support (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart).

I have a virtual machine on which I have installed the D365FO system.

I modified the standard msal-config:

```
const msalConfig: Msal.Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "XXXX",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com",
    redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/fallbackauthdialog.html",
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};

var requestObj: Object = {
  scopes: [`https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`, 'https://erp.dynamics.com/AX.FullAccess','https://erp.dynamics.com/Odata.FullAccess','https://erp.dynamics.com/CustomService.FullAccess']
};
```

The URL "https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com" is redirected to the computer's IP using the hosts file.
I created an app registration in the Azure portal (the ClientID is used above).

If I now request the token via the add-in in Outlook and reuse the token in Postman to retrieve data, I only get an unauthorized response.

Nothing happens when I use the AddIn in the Outlook Web version (normally my name should be printed in the text box). It works in the desktop version (but the token still doesn't work in D365FO)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share exact error message you are seeing in Outlook Web App? A screenshot of the console with error message will help.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. Here is the screenshot: [link]https://imgur.com/a/7f6jxpI

Comment: To help you in the situation we need to know a few more things :
1. Is the token, that the add-in fetches, not valid ? Since I can see errors regarding the same in console. The flow isn't clear how exactly is the control flowing ?
2. You fetch the token from add-in and then manually try to retrieve data using postman and that fails ?
3. I can see in the screenshot that the error being thrown is login failure. Is that working in desktop version ? As in what exactly works in desktop version and what fails for web add-ins ?
4. Does the desktop version mean outlook client for mac or windows ?

Comment: Can you please provide answers to previously asked questions? Can you also tell us if you are trying to fix "Outlook Addin" usage or "Postman" usage?

Comment: So the only problem is with Outlook.com, my Outlook 2019 works perfectly. I just re-created the project (described here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator )  and didn't change anything in the code or on Problem is still the same. I am trying to fix the Outlook add-in. The token is valid, if i try to get data using Postman and the retrieved token from the addin , i can access my personal informations.

Comment: We tried both JavaScript and TypeScript version of the SSO add-in and we are able to fetch Graph content. You say token is valid but from your error screenshot, looks like we are going to the fallback auth. Can you share more information here? Do you see an auth dialog when you click on the button? Can you check whether https://localhost:3000/auth call succeeds?